# Delete entire child object (at child level) and see removal in parent array

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, eventemitter

I am building an Angular 2 app.

I have an array in my parent class `ParentComponent` called `childObjects`. Based on the length of the `childObjects` array, `ChildComponents` get created e.g., if `childObjects` is of length 3, then 3 `ChildComponents` get created. During the runtime of my application, the user has the option to delete one of those childObjects **at the child level**, i.e., there is a Delete button/function in the ChildComponent.

How do you go about deleting the entire object (in my case a ChildComponent), and updating the parent array that still holds a reference to it (in childObjects)? I know how to do this with an EventEmitter, but I am wondering if it is possible to avoid using EventEmitters.

Basically, how can you remove/update a child component, then have those changes (or deletion) reflected in the parent component that contains the object in an array without EventEmitters (if possible)?

Comment: The child could use [a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) to inform the parent that the deletion occurred.